# Respecting MVC framework

Tags: codeigniter, controller

I'm using [CodeIgniter Framework](http://codeigniter.com/) in order to build a web application as follows.

My default controller is something like this,

```
class Start extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() 
    {  
        $view_data = array(
            'foo' => 'bar',
            'top_bar_view' => 'top_bar_view',
            'top_bar_params' => array(
                'param1' => 'val1',
                'param2' => 'val2',
                'param3' => 'val3', 
                'param4' => 'val4',
                'param5' =>  'val5'
            )
        );
        $this->load->view('main_view', $view_data);
    }
}
```

which loads the main_view, that is kind of master page, where I load the view file that I'm passing with $view_data.

Then, on this top_bar_view I would like to call a controller in order to build a menu depending on some data. For now, I accomplish this using an AJAX call inside this partial view.

```
script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.post('index.php/menu/givemenu', {}, function(data) { 
             $('#topMenuBar').append(data); });
        });

<img alt="alt_data" src="assets/img/<?php echo $image_name; ?>" />
<div>
    <img alt="<?php echo $descricao_editora; ?>" src="assets/img/<?php echo $image_name; ?>" />
</div>
<div class="divSpacer20pxRight"></div>
<div class="divTituloProduto">
    <?php echo $titulo_produto; ?>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="topMenuBar" class="divTopMenuBar"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Is this correct and respects the MVC Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally don't like that kind of solution but "Is it correct" is relative but I would create a `MY_Controller` that will be extended from all my other controllers and add the `givemenu` method so I can call it from all controllers. On your controllers `index` method, you call it and add its return to your array and pass it to the view.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Why not create a helper or library to do the work of your givemenu method?

Or use a template parser like Lex? https://github.com/happyninjas/lex

If you just include something it will make your Controllers and Views much easier to maintain, and will mean you don't have to rely on JavaScript.